# Getting ClassNotFoundException when deploying application is referring Shared Library Weblogic

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

We have one web application which is deployed on weblogic.

This application is build using maven and references a library via dependency as a result it is part of WEB-INF/libs folder.

However we want to deploy that library and move out of war bundling.

Hence we excluded it out war packaging. We create another war and added that library as a dependency in it, and deployed as library.

In previous web application,
I refer that library as follows:

```
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd">
     <wls:library-ref> 
        <wls:library-name>my-libraries</wls:library-name> 
         <wls:specification-version>1.0.0</wls:specification-version>
     </wls:library-ref> 
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Then i deployed library followed by application which uses that library, but application fails to deploy with `ClassNotFoundException` for class inside jar within that library deployed.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check that your shared lib is really deployed as a shared lib and not a standard web application ? Check also that both lib and application are targeted to same servers.

Comment: one more point, if you have really created a shared lib as a war file it must be referenced in the weblogic.xml deployment descriptor and not in the weblogic-application.xml deployment descriptor. This one can only reference shared libs which are bundled in ear.

Comment: yes all above already done, i am trying to install that as an ear now

Comment: see my second comment.

Comment: yeah let me try with war and put reference of library in weblogic.xml

Comment: kudos works brilliantly :)